# OptionalDataException in java

Tags: java

```
package com.n;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class S implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    transient int i;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException {

        ObjectOutputStream oos = 
             new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\jav\\f.txt"));

        S obj1 = new S(10);
        oos.writeInt(obj1.i);
        oos.writeObject(obj1);

        ObjectInputStream ois = 
             new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("c:\\jav\\f.txt"));

        System.out.println("Object contains >> " + ois.readObject());

        System.out.println("Transient variable written separately yields >> i =" 
                           + ois.readInt());
    }

    public S(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "i= " + i;
    }

}
```

The code above throws

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.OptionalDataException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.n.S.main(S.java:27)
```

but when I interchange the output lines like

```
 System.out.println("Transient variable written separately yields >> i =" + ois.readInt());
 System.out.println("Object contains >> " + ois.readObject());
```

It runs fine. But why is it so? Do I have to write as well as read the serialized primitive values first and then read or write the object? And what is an `OptionalDataException`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to read data from an ObjectInputStream in exactly the same order as they were written to the ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: that is not true Ted cause even if i change the write lines to  oos.writeObject(obj1);
oos.writeInt(obj1.i); and reading in the same order still it gives the same exception..The only time it runs fine is when I read the primitve before the object

Comment: @Nav Try closing `oos` before trying to read the file. When I added `oos.close()` after the writes, your code worked for me (after reversing either the read order or the write order).

Comment: I got it now .The problem was that I was not closing the file. Thanks guys. :)

Comment: @Nav - Yep. The data was stuck in a buffer somewhere and not making it to the file, so the ObjectInputStream wasn't seeing it.

Comment: Hi guys. What java version are you using? I have the same problem but closing the output stream does not solve it.

Comment: @istik - The Java version has nothing to do with this issue. Check the order in which you write and then read items. Without seeing your code and the fill stack trace, it's impossible  to know what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

please see the definition of the exception: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OptionalDataException.html

You have a primitive before an object as stored (you wrote int before object). The document says:

> An attempt was made to read an object when the next element in the stream is primitive data. In this case, the OptionalDataException's length field is set to the number of bytes of primitive data immediately readable from the stream, and the eof field is set to false.

so yes, you need to readInt first.

HTH!

Comment: Yeah I saw that before I came here but, didn't quite understand why. So its a rule then to read the primitive before the object right ???

Comment: nope, it just means that you should read object where there's an object and read primitives where there are primitives :-) you should know the structure of your serialized data.