# sending String using ObjectInputStream. Error: OptionalDataException

Tags: java, sockets

I am want to send a String - "HelloWorld" using ObjectInputStream from the client to server.
The server will receive "HelloWorld" and print it out on console.

Both of them are connected on localhost and port 4445.

I received a error at the server side

```
Error: java.io.OptionalDataException
```

Client.java

```
private ObjectOutputStream output;  
private ObjectInputStream input;    

@Override
public void run() { 
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost",4445);
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            output.writeChars("HelloWorld");
            output.flush();
        }   
}
```

Server.java

```
private ObjectOutputStream output;  
private ObjectInputStream input;    
private Object message;

@Override
public void run() {         
    try {       
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); 
        while(true) {   
            try {
                message =(String)input.readObject();
                System.out.println(message);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
   }catch(IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + exception);
    }
```

I read up on this error and it states that this exception will be thrown when

```
An attempt was made to read an object when the next element in the stream is 
primitive data. In this case, the OptionalDataException's length field is set
to the number of bytes of primitive data immediately readable from the stream, 
and the eof field is set to false.
```

I am quite lost after reading this explanation, so does that mean that you cannot send a String data type using ObjectInputStream?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OptionalDataException in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630494/optionaldataexception-in-java)

Comment: @alfasin I think this is not a duplicate of the link you gave.  In this case the OP does not realize that writeChars does not write an Object.

Answer (score 1):

when you are using `writeChars` you are not writing A string you are writing a series of primitives.  Use `writeObject` instead.

As per [javaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeChars(java.lang.String))

```
public void writeChars(String str)
                throws IOException
Writes a String as a sequence of chars.
```

Answer (score 0):

Chars sent by `writeChars` can be read only by several `readChar`. Use writeUTF / readUTF instead